# How to display GameCenter leaderboard on tvOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, tvos, apple-tv, game-center-leaderboard

I *think* I followed all the required steps to support leaderboards in my game (and they work just fine on iOS), however on tvOS it is not possible to configure the `GKGameCenterViewController` to show a specific leaderboard, the `LeaderboardIdentifier` property is simply missing (just like the `ViewState`):

```
var leaderboardController = new GKGameCenterViewController ();

// Unavailable on tvOS
/*
leaderboardController.ViewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Default;
leaderboardController.LeaderboardIdentifier = "myLeaderboardId";
*/ 

leaderboardController.Finished += (sender, e) =>
{
  leaderboardController.DismissViewController (true, null);
}

PresentViewController (leaderboardController, true, null);
```

Instead of using these properties, I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770956/how-to-open-gamecenter-in-tvos). I notice that this will generate a `GKGameCenterContent.plist` file in the final app bundle. I double checked the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>GKLeaderboards</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>identifier</key>
            <string>myLeaderboardId</string>
            <key>onDemandResourcesTag</key>
            <string>com.apple.gamecenter.Leaderboard</string>
            <key>posterImageName</key>
            <string>Leaderboard/Poster</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This looks absolutely correct, also the images are of course in the bundle. Still, using the code above to show the game center controller will only give me the achievements screen and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a leaderboard to Assets.xassets. There you can enter the identifier:

[image]

The code to show the leaderboard:

```
@IBAction func openLeaderboard(sender: AnyObject) {

    let gcViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
    self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: OK. I haven't followed the link. Just saw, that this was my question

Comment: For me it worked fine. I guess you have successfully created the leaderboard in iTunesConnect and you are using the same leaderboard in your iOS and AppleTV game?

Comment: Yeah...the iOS version works fine. The problem is: I have to export the leaderboard config to include it into Xamarin Stuidio. I presume I'm missing one step...current XS does not support tvOS leaderboards.

Comment: I'm just creating my leaderboard for my second AppleTV game. If it works I'll let you know what I did different. Could take till tomorrow.