# How to display GameCenter leaderboard sets on tvOS?

Tags: tvos

I have been trying to add multiple leaderboards that are in leaderboard sets to my tvOS target of my iOS game.
I already have a game on the tvOS App Store so I know I have to add the leaderboards in the asset catalogue, as described here 
[How to display GameCenter leaderboard on tvOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097474/how-to-display-gamecenter-leaderboard-on-tvos)

Now when trying to add multiple leaderboards I assumed you would add each leaderboard set with the corresponding image in Xcode (with correct leaderboard set ID), however this doesn't really work.

I can open the game enter menu on my TV and see the leaderboard sets, they even say how many leaderboards they contain, however clicking on it just says no data.

I tried signing out and back into game enter because you sometimes get the "no data" message on iOS in sandbox mode and a sign out/in fixes it. That didn't work.

Surely I don't have to add 40 leaderboards to my asset catalogue, that seems ridiculous

Has anyone done this before, I don't know what I am missing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to actually add each leaderboard set in Xcode asset catalogue with corresponding ID in the inspector on the right. Than for each leaderboard in a set you have to add the leaderboard. This seems madness if you have a lot of leaderboards but I haven't figured out another way yet.